# Boilerplate Vue Project Fails on router-link and router-view

Tags: vue.js

I used `vue create` to create a new view project with Babel, TypeScript, Router and Unit Testing. I then installed axios using npm.

Having done no other changes, I served the application by navigating to the src directory and running `vue serve`.

The resulting boilerplate application fails to load with the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register
>   the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to
>   provide the "name" option.
>
> found in
>
> --->  at App.vue

My own research shows that this error usually happens when you fail to call Vue.Use(). However, my router.ts file does so:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import Home from './views/Home.vue';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({   routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/About.vue'),
    },   ], });
```

Does anyone know what is wrong here? Given I haven't changed anything, could it be a config issue?

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

The issue was that I was running the server the wrong way. I was using:

```
vue serve src/App.vue
```

when I should have used:

```
npm run serve
```

After that change, it started to work.

Comment: Actually I did noticed that but thought you might have had a custom npm run command in your vue.config.js, updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to navigate to the `src` folder, just navigate to the root directory of your application, then run `npm run serve`.

Comment: I tried that originally, but I got the following error:

Failed to locate entry file in H:\Data\ApacheDocRoot\SoftAccounts\soft-accounts.
Valid entry file should be one of: main.js, index.js, App.vue or app.vue.